# Makefile - Add objects to folder

Tags: makefile

I don't understand why this works:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -shared
SRC = src/file.c
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)

test: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

And this doesn't:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -shared
SRC = file.c
OBJ := $(addprefix output/, $(SRC:.c=.o))
SRC := $(addprefix src/, $(SRC))

test: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

As I'm only trying to make an output folder for all OBJ.
GCC tells me there's no rule to make "output/file.o" which leaves me perplex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is a built-in rule that knows how to build `X.o` from `X.c` for any `X`, but there isn't a built-in rule that knows how to build `output/X.o` from `src/X.c`.  How could there be such a built-in rule, that knows about whatever special directory structure you come up with?

You'll have to define your own rule:

```
output/%.o : src/%.c
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```